# Is it OK to use store as storage for component data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have read Redux doc and found out it is like the only way to share data between components, globally, and it seems like it works like on top of contexts.

The question: Can I use Redux Store for data I do not need to share across the application, like, items list got from the network, etc?

What is the best case to use Redux Store?

P.S. Edited the question about Angular as is cannot create a new one

Comment: I personally think opening an issue on their github page is more appropriate.

Comment: I think here more Angular developers. It is the question to the community.

Comment: [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: Isn't the MCV structure usually used in backend frameworks, not frontend? Anyway, a component in angular is a small reusable component. Thereby the name I supose.

Comment: But it is not. They call top-level components for Views as components also. You cannot reuse it later (practically), they have completely unique logic inside.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up Angular terminology and methodology terminology.

MVC (standing for Model, View, Controller, not Module, View, Component!) is a methodology, which divides an application into three concerns: business logic, presentation logic, and what glues them together.

Within this terminology, an Angular component is a marriage of controller and view: a template that shows how a component should look, and code that specifies how a component should behave.

Comment: Top-level components for routes have their names also: Scenes (in set-top-box development), View, Routes, something like that. They can replace each other. Why do they call it Components? We must write clear modules, clear things, and if their terminology is not enough precise, why do the community use it? This is the question. It does not depend on where it comes from (general terminology, or Angular terminology), it is about the clear understandable meaning of things.

Comment: If would they call it "Service", it does not mean that top-level components are services. Here is the same thing :)